# Error when using Powershell in a batch file to get the total size and the count of a current directory

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

As a newbie to Powershell (PS), I want to use Powershell in a current batch file launched from CMD to get the total size and the count of all files, excluding files in the sub-folders, in the current directory.

Again, this task will be incorporated in the middle of a batch file, which means PS will be used for this task only, whilst the rest is still running on CMD.  Ultimately, I want to export the result of this task to a text file.

Here is my try in the batch file:

```
start powershell.exe -noexit ($colitems = Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object Length -Sum)
" Total size: "+ "{0:N2}" -f ($colitems.sum / 1MB) + " MB, and" +  $colitems.count + " total files"
```

Unfortunately, the process gets an error:

> 'Measure-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

If you have any advice to fix the issue, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its because pipe (`|`) means "output the result of command to the command of the right side of the pipe". And it is with higher prio than the other commands.

`-noexit` will not execute the rest of the commands in the script as powershell commands. If you want to [combine both batch and powershell](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5526&start=15#p49229) in one file you can try this:

```
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

(for %%I in ("%~f0";%*) do @echo(%%~I) | ^
powershell -noprofile "$argv = $input | ?{$_}; iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"

goto :EOF
: end batch / begin powershell #>

($colitems = Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object Length -Sum)
" Total size: "+ "{0:N2}" -f ($colitems.sum / 1MB) + " MB, and" +  $colitems.count + " total files"
```